# How to SQL Query records from Multiple that Equal 0?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table that has multiple duplicate records in the first column (ID records), but has varying numerical data in the second column.

I want to be able to identify which ID records have 0 for all of their numerical records.

For example the table can look like:

```
ID Value

1  2

1  2

1  0

2  0

2  0  

2  0
```

I would want to only identify ID 2 because all the values are equal to 0. I don't want ID 1 because there are values > 0

Sorry if this isn't formatted properly or confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE <> 0)
```

This will take all ID in the table where there is not a row where the value is non-zero.

Comment: So, what I'm doing is first saying I want unique rows from my table, then adding condition that the ID is not matching to a distinct record that is not 0?

Comment: Maybe the DISTINCT in the inner query is a little overhead

Comment: @fordo19 - yes basically.  except it won't happen in that order -- the list of ones that are not 0 will be found first.

Comment: I was actually about to ask that, is it necessary (the distinct in the subquery)? Is it some sort of way to make it faster?

Comment: @JoachimSauer - nope.  That will make the query faster the optimizer can ignore duplicate IDs after it filters the first one into the sub-query results.

Comment: @fordo19 - exactly -- the distinct could speed it up not slow it down. (depends on the platform / optimizer)

Comment: Okay, thank you, this makes sense, I guess when I get more experience I can think this way -- figure out which ones have value <> 0, then just choose the the distinct ones that don't match this, I had been trying to figure out the other way, determining how to isolate those that had value = 0  and removing the others.

Comment: @fordo19 - yes the use of `NOT IN` and `IN` will come naturally with time.  This is exactly how SQL is designed to handle this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might use "NOT IN":

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM table1
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM table1 WHERE Value <> 0)
```

Comment: Looks very much like my answer.

Comment: Think we wrote it at the same time. Didn't see yours.

Comment: We don't have to wonder.  They have timestamps.  Mine was over 5 mins before yours.

Comment: @Hogan I'm sorry. I really didn't see yours before I posted my answer.

Comment: Its ok it eod on Friday and I'm being snarky

Comment: @Hogan - And yours is accepted. Then everything should be ok ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.id AND Value <> 0)
```

"Select all records whose ID is not in the set of records that have a non-zero Value."

Comment: Sort of new to SQL, am I selecting from another select statement? Also, what is the significance of "SELECT 1", I've never seen this before.

Comment: @fordo19 - that is called a sub-query.  Very common in SQL.  This technique of doing a sub-query join without a join statement in a NOT EXISTS is very old-school and not used much anymore.

Comment: @Hogan I would disagree.  `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` generally perform better for large data sets than an `IN ()` expression, although most modern query engines will optimize them to be the same.  However, in any subquery where you want to join against more than one field, such as if you have a composite key, you *must* use the `EXISTS` syntax.  Furthermore, `IN`, and particularly `NOT IN`, IMX, can be screwed up by `NULL` values, while `EXISTS` will not be as long as you pick a static value.

Comment: @BaconBits - I'm guessing you use DB2 or Oracle since those favor EXISTS.  MSQL favors IN and NOT IN.  But you make a good point... it is certainly true this would perform better on DB2

Comment: @fordo19 The `SELECT 1` is just a non-`NULL` value for the DB to test against.  Since we're not using the subquery in the results, we just need something to satisfy the query syntax (i.e., you can't select nothing).  You'll often see this as `SELECT *`, which works too, but since we don't want the query engine to bother looking up the names of the table fields, we can just use a `1` instead.  Most modern databases will treat them the same, however.

Comment: @Hogan No, I predominantly use MS SQL.  I use `EXISTS` primarily because the schema I work with most has mostly composite primary keys.  Either way, most modern RDBMSs will recognize both syntaxes as an anti-join and resolve them identically.  Since `IN` is never required, I've just stopped using it except for static lists.  `IN` vs `EXISTS` vs `JOIN` is a pretty common debate topic on SQL blogs.